# Javascript [object, Object] - How transform in simple Object

Tags: javascript

I can't get the data to post to the frontend.
**Filtered: Files**

```
node:
  teste1: url1.yml
  teste2: url2.yml
  teste3: ''
node:
  teste4: ''
```

I read this file and send to organizer.js ([key: value], 'node' )

**FILE - organizer.js:**

```
export default function organizer(filtered, type) {
  const rawData = Object.entries(filtered)
  let projects = {}

  let completed = rawData
    .filter(([key, value]) => value !== '')
    .map((item, index, array) => {
      let isComplete = {}
      item.id = uuidv4()
      item.name = item[0]
      item.url = item[1]
      writeFile(item[0], item[1])
      item.iscomplete = true
      item.file = readFile(item[0])
      item.items = flattenArray(item.file)
      item.name = item[0].replaceAll('-', ' ')
      item.splice(0, 2)
      isComplete = { ...item }
      return isComplete
    })

  let incompleted = rawData
    .filter(([key, value]) => value === '')
    .map((item, index, array) => {
      let notComplete = {}
      item.id = uuidv4()
      item.name = item[0]
      item.url = ''
      item.iscomplete = false
      item.name = item[0].replaceAll('-', ' ')
      item.splice(0, 2)
      notComplete = { ...item }
      return notComplete
    })

  const arrayData = Array.from([...completed, ...incompleted])
  console.log(arrayData)
```

In the organizer file I get an Array with objects, but when importing the data to send to the frontend I get [object, Object]

1. I tried using Object.fromEntries() but it didn't work.
2. I tried using forEach() and destructuring da data = {...completed, ...incompleted}
3. I tried using new Map inside completed and incompleted

Maybe I have to adopt another way of treating data but I can't imagine another solution.

Answer (score 0):

`"[object Object]"` is what you get if you try to convert an Object into a String.

It seems that your http framework doesn't handle that for you

Search for `my-http-framework-json` package to handle that for you or use `JSON.stringify` to convert object to string and `JSON.parse` to convert it back

Comment: App.js = app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); And when I try to use JSON.parse(arrayData) I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: 1. const arrayData = Array.from([...completed, ...incompleted])
2. const toString = JSON.stringify(arrayData)
3. const res = JSON.parse(toString) - Same result [object Object]

Comment: Console.log everything just before sending, the error is likeliy there then